# PowerBI Matrix - Each row different calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to make a PowerBI Matrix where each row is a different calculation. Below is what I would do if it was in Excel.

How can I do individual calculated rows in PowerBI Matrix?

[image]

Comment: It didn't appear to work for me. I've been able to set up a Matrix using calculated columns when setting it up, which appears to be working.